# Excluding child values

Tags: api, symfony, serialization

I have a property within my Entity which links to another Entity:

```
 /**
 * @Groups({"bookReviews"})
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Book\MainBundle\Entity\Book", inversedBy="reviews")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bookID", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $bookID;
```

Within my controller when this is called:

```
    public function getReviewsAction()
{
    $serializer = $this->get('serializer');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $reviews = $em->getRepository('BookMainBundle:Review')->findAll();
    $data = $serializer->serialize($reviews, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('Default')));
    return $this->handleView($this->view($reviews));
}
```

This retrieves a JSON with the following result:

```
{
 "id": 17,
 "book_i_d": {
 "id": 10,
 "author": "J.K Rowling",
 "title": "Harry Potter: Philosopher's Stone",
 "posted": "2017-01-03T04:19:18+0000",
 "summary": "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone is the first novel in the Harry Potter series and J. K. Rowling's debut novel, first published in 1997 by Bloomsbury. It was published in the United States as Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone by Scholastic Corporation in 1998. The plot follows Harry Potter, a young wizard who discovers his magical heritage as he makes close friends and a few enemies in his first year at the Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry. With the help of his friends, Harry faces an attempted comeback by the dark wizard Lord Voldemort, who killed Harry's parents, but failed to kill Harry when he was just a year old.",
 "image": "cde5910f46d0e6bed33ffa18aa24ec5c.jpeg"
},
"posted": "2017-01-03T04:19:19+0000",
"review": "The author started Harry's journey with this book. It's the beginning and it's bloody brilliant!"
}
```

However, as you notice.. irrelevant information of the book is retrieved. At this point, the only detail I want to retrieve of the book is the book's ID.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

Create specific method in the Review class

```
public function findAllAndOnlyBookId()
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('a.id, b.id')
        ->from('BookMainBundle\Review', 'a')
        ->leftJoin('a.book_id', 'b');
    ;

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

And after call your method

```
 $reviews = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('BookMainBundle:Review')-> findAllAndOnlyBookId();
```

P.S. I don't know if the query or path is correct because I need to try It, but the concept is clear I think

Comment: Is there anyway of achieving this using exclusions, groups or depths? I feel as if this shouldn't be added within an ApiBundle

Comment: I think no, my solution is clean and very used. I prefer to create query class to manage my query

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions here.

1. Create a virtual property for serializer and assign to a custom method in your entity that returns id only, remove $bookID from serializer context at all.

   @Serializer\VirtualProperty()

   @Serializer\SerializedName("book_id")

   @Serializer\Groups({"bookReviewes"})
2. The other option is to correctly assign serializer annotations in the linked entity. User different context for all the fields.

Just make sure you're serializing the entities with the right context. Because now you're doing it with "Default" group but in the annotation it's set to "bookReviews".